# How to make image asset with transparent background in Android studio? (with option add image asset)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have image with transparent background.

When i add image to resource folder, my background changes to white. 
(with android studio add image asset option)

[image]

If i put image directly to resource file, image background stays transparent.

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher

Comment: you can use given link to generate icons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select **"Action Bar and Tab Icons"** instead of **"Launcher Icons"** and you'll get the transparent background as required for all the images.

Comment: Amazing answer, wish this was more popular!

Comment: if I do this now the image is just gray...

Comment: You can always put tint to it or if they are vector icon, you can change its color

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
myImage.setAlpha(127); //value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it easily by doing the below, BTW the gray circle is original in the image itself.**

[image]

**It will create you these**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the

**Icon type** --- > **Lagacy only**

and

**shape** -- > **none**

as follow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is to be done in order to set the app icons generated to have transparent background

Edit the ic_launcher_background.xml file generated and set it like below:

This will remove the default background generated to be transparent color only.

Remove all the path definitions and only have the following one

```
<path android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:pathData="M0,0h108v108h-108z"/>
```